# How to attach a bar in a doorframe

Tags: door-frame, anchor

For a homemade fitness equipment I need to attach a bar to a door frame without using screws or modifying/damaging the doorframe. The only idea I had was to use a pullup bar which one can clamp into the door frame, something [like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0016BNDXI)

The problem is that the bar has to be heavy duty anchored, say it should be able to hold forces equivalent to min. 120 kg in each direction. I don't want a solution where something is anchored in a closed door!

The project was inspired by [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lonkJjBeFKg) and [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HztKutgiim0) but will be a bit more complicated. I sketched a basic example how it will be used in the second image below (however the device will become more complicated and powerfull, but the problem of anchoring it in the doorframe without closing the door remains the same).

[image]

[image]

**Edit:** The solution (once built) should be easy to mount and unmount in just a few minutes.

**Edit:** The top bar on the second picture is not the (main) problem. There I can use my other pull up bar ([Iron Gym](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001EJMS6K)) which is more secure and heavy duty but which I can mount only on the top of the doorframe so it doesn't help with the bar on the bottom.

Comment: If you can't modify the doorframe, why not build something freestanding that you can modify?

Comment: @BMitch Because I don't have enough space. Something freestanding would be large and heavy or one would have to anchor it somewhere in a wall as well (but I don't want to make any holes into the wall...)

Comment: The top bar will have a lot of down pressure on it. The hinged portion I drew in will not only act as a spreader to hold the sides in place, but it will act as a strong mount for the pull bar. The spreader has to be there anyway, so I was intending to use it as a mount for the pull bar. The store bought one could go in its place, but it will be another loose part to add to the assembly, compared to one that is attached to it by a hinge and only needs to be swung up and secured with the latch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reline your jamb with another material that you can screw into. The pressure you will subject the door frame to is really needing something screwed into it. To just use pressure has the strong possibility of deforming or worse, cracking your jamb, depends on where the shims are placed behind the jamb, but you cant see them, unless you take it apart, not a good idea, totally counterproductive.[image: Exercise door]

There is more to sketch regarding the assembly how it fits together at the bottom. The idea is, it may be complicated to initially assemble/make, but that time spent now will pay off on how easy it is to assemble and take down.

I see it being 4 pieces, a plywood bottom with pulley mechanism attached, a hinged door head mounted to one of the side jamb liners with the pull up bar and tension bands attached and the ropes to link it all together.[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I think I need a sketch to understand what you mean.

Comment: Will this sketch do that I added in?

Comment: Thanks. but I don't really understand it. Can I take for the blue things just wooden boards? How are they attached to the frame? Just by the fact hat the upper blue part attached by the hinge and the latch presses them to the door frame? Is the idea that I can attach the pull up bar with screws on the bottom?

Comment: I will modify the sketch to help understand, and I have another idea

Comment: Now I understand it better. Can you add some more details about the assemble and how it fits together at the bottom?

Comment: I am back at work today, I will try to get one together tonight

Comment: Here is the sketch, I hope it gets the rest of the idea across. This sketch is one single part of the rig, the plywood base with the rest of its installed components. The upper sketch as you may know, details the jamb liner and how it relates to the jamb